# ¿Por que me sale error en el switch/case? Java

Tags: java, if

Se solicita desarrollar el algoritmo que permita analizar el comportamiento de las ventas de la
Heladería “La dulzura”.

Para esto se solicita ingresar una muestra de 5 ventas durante un período de
tiempo.

Se debe ingresar:

a. Tamaño del helado:

i. c (Vaso chico)

ii. m (Vaso mediano)

iii. g (Cucurucho)

b. Cantidad

c. Precio

Se debe calcular:

a. Importe total vendido

b. Importe promedio por venta

c. Orden de las presentaciones en función de las ventas (Que tamaño de helado se vende más, cual
menos, y cual está en el medio)

*Cuando ingreso : vaso chico o vaso mediano me sale error , pero cuando ingreso cucurucho no y no puedo encontrar el error.

```
int ventas = 6;
    String helados = " ";
    int cantidad1 = 0;
    int cantidad2 = 0;
    int cantidad3 = 0;
    int precio1 = 20;
    int precio2 = 30;
    int precio3 = 15;
    int total1 = 0;
    int total2 = 0;
    int total3 = 0;
    int totalVendido = 0;
    double promedioVenta = 0;
    int cantidad = 0;

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 1; i < ventas; i++) {

        System.out.println(i + ".Ingrese tamaño de helado (vaso chico / vaso mediano / cucurucho) : ");
        helados = teclado.next();
        System.out.println(i + ".Ingrese Cantidad : ");
        cantidad = teclado.nextInt();

        switch (helados) {

        case "vaso chico ":

            total1 = precio1 * cantidad;

            cantidad1++;

            System.out.println("Total : " + total1);

            break;

        case "vaso mediano ":

            total2 = precio2 * cantidad;

            cantidad2++;

            System.out.println("Total : " + total2);

            break;

        case "cucurucho":

            total3 = precio3 * cantidad;

            cantidad3++;

            System.out.println("Total : " + total3);


            break;

        default:

            System.out.println("Error!");

            break;

        }

    }

    totalVendido = cantidad1 + cantidad2 + cantidad3;

    System.out.println("Importe total vendido : " + totalVendido);

    promedioVenta = totalVendido / 5;

    System.out.println("Importe promedio por venta : " + promedioVenta);

    if (cantidad1 > cantidad2 && cantidad2 > cantidad3) {

        System.out.println("1°.Vaso Chico . \n 2°.Vaso Mediano . \n 3°.Cucurucho .");
    }

    else if (cantidad2 > cantidad3 && cantidad3 > cantidad1) {

        System.out.println("1°.Vaso Mediano . \n 2°.Cucurucho . \n 3°.Vaso Chico .");

    }

    if (cantidad3 > cantidad1 && cantidad1 > cantidad2) {

        System.out.println("1°.Cucurucho . \n 2°.Vaso Chico . \n 3°.Vaso Mediano .");

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es por que tienes declarado tu case como "vaso mediano " & "vaso chico ".

Nota que al final de la cadena, hay un espacio, por consecuencia si tu escribes "vaso chico", esa cadena es diferente a la que tienes condicionada

Comment: Tiene un espacio al final de la cadena.

Comment: Ya lo arregle pero ahora cuando tengo que ingresar la cantidad me pone : Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at tareas.edu.ar.Heladeria2PorTeclado.main(Heladeria2PorTeclado.java:32)

Comment: y hace referencia a cantidad = teclado.nextInt();

Comment: @computer96 Eso es un problema distinto y debería ser una pregunta distinta (aunque estoy casi seguro de que si buscas por ese error encontrarás que ya está respondida). Si esta respuesta te ha solucionado el problema que tenías deberías marcarla como correcta.